# **at** not **hearing** the person

Tags: grammar

a) You should check connection, **at** not **hearing** the person you are calling?

Is it correct to use preposition «at» in that sense? Shouldn’t there be «on»?
Is there any difference between these prepositions for native speakers?

Comment: Local variation. Could be how people would say it in some localities.

Comment: Dan, thank you! Google, though, produce more "on" results.

Comment: "...if you cannot hear the person you are calling" would be more natural.